# How to setup Gitlab-omnibus with non-bundled web-server?

Tags: nginx, debian-wheezy, gitlab

### Install

1. I installed the `gitlab` package through the omnibus package on `debian 7` (version`7.8.1-omnibus-1_amd64.deb`) ;
2. change the settings as describe in [Using a non-bundled web-server](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/omnibus-gitlab/blob/master/doc/settings/nginx.md#using-a-non-bundled-web-server)
3. run the reconfigure command: `sudo gitlab-ctl reconfigure` (complete without error).

### Nginx

I got no `nginx`' config for this gitlab except for what the package might have created with the following `/etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb` file:

```ruby
external_url 'http://git.mydomain.fr'
web_server['external_users'] = ['www-data']
nginx['enable'] = false
ci_nginx['enable'] = false
```

### Logs

#### /var/log/nginx/gitlab_error.log

```
2015/02/28 14:29:16 [alert] 4137#0: *14738 768 worker_connections are not enough while connecting to upstream, client: x.x.128.194, server: git.mydomain.fr, request: "GET / HTTP/1.0", upstream
: "http://x.x.128.194:80/", host: "git.mydomain.fr"
```

#### /var/log/nginx/gitlab_access.log

In the acces.log I got hundreds of requests on `/`.

```
x.x.128.194 - - [28/Feb/2015:14:29:16 +0100] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 500 186 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:37.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/37.0"
x.x.128.194 - - [28/Feb/2015:14:29:16 +0100] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 500 186 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:37.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/37.0"
x.x.128.194 - - [28/Feb/2015:14:29:16 +0100] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 500 186 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:37.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/37.0"x.x.128.194 - - [28/Feb/2015:14:29:16 +0100] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 500 186 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:37.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/37.0"
x.x.128.194 - - [28/Feb/2015:14:29:16 +0100] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 500 186 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:37.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/37.0"
```

### Question

When trying to contact the serve locally using `links2` or externally I got an error `502 Bad Gateway`.

- do I need to create a custom nginx' config ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Continuing to explore I find the `/var/opt/gitlab/` directory and solve this doing:

```
sudo ln -s /var/opt/gitlab/nginx/conf/gitlab-http.conf /etc/nginx/sites-available/
sudo ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-{available,enabled}/gitlab-http.conf
sudo service nginx reload
```

Comment: I̶ ̶w̶o̶u̶l̶d̶ ̶m̶a̶r̶k̶ ̶t̶h̶i̶s̶ ̶a̶s̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶ ̶a̶n̶s̶w̶e̶r̶.̶ ̶I̶t̶ ̶w̶o̶r̶k̶s̶ ̶a̶s̶ ̶f̶a̶r̶ ̶a̶s̶ ̶I̶ ̶c̶a̶n̶ ̶t̶e̶l̶l̶,̶ ̶a̶n̶d̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶r̶e̶ ̶i̶s̶ ̶n̶o̶ ̶b̶e̶t̶t̶e̶r̶ ̶p̶r̶a̶c̶t̶i̶c̶e̶/̶s̶o̶l̶u̶t̶i̶o̶n̶ Gives 404 errors even at login. Is it a mistake on my end?

Comment: Yes, it was a mistake on my end. Works!

Comment: Note, this no longer works completely, as you'll get a `unknown log format "gitlab_access" in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/gitlab-http.conf:52` error.

Comment: The following fixes the log format problem
`sudo ln -s /var/opt/gitlab/nginx/conf/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/sites-available/`
and `sudo ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-{available,enabled}/nginx.conf`

Answer (score 2):

As for gitlab 8, we cannot symlink to the default gitlab-http.conf anymore because the bundle webserver will not be installed when we set `nginx['enable'] = false`.

Just download the right web server configs from [GitLab recipes repository](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-recipes/tree/master/web-server) and change `YOUR_SERVER_FQDN` with
your preferred domain name.

See [here for detail instructions](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/omnibus-gitlab/blob/master/doc/settings/nginx.md#using-a-non-bundled-web-server) on how to install gitlab using non-bundled web-server.

Answer (score 1):

To ensure that user are accessible your Nginx user (usually www-data or nginx) should be added to the gitlab-www group:

```
sudo usermod -aG gitlab-www nginx
```

or

```
sudo usermod -aG gitlab-www www-data
```

Answer (score 1):

If you symlinked gitlab-http.conf and then got :

> unknown log format "gitlab_access" in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/gitlab-http.conf

Just add the `log_format` directives from `/var/opt/gitlab/nginx/conf/nginx.conf` to your global nginx configuration :

```
http {
  ...
  log_format gitlab_access '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" $status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" "$http_user_agent"';
  log_format gitlab_ci_access '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" $status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" "$http_user_agent"';
  log_format gitlab_mattermost_access '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" $status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" "$http_user_agent"';
  ...
}
```